# Remove leading whitespace in Mako template

Tags: templates, whitespace, mako, removing-whitespace

In a use case for autogenerating code from a Mako template, I'd like to have a nice syntax to remove leading whitespace (similar to removing newlines with `\` at the end of a line).

The following code

```py
from mako.template import Template

# 1) Bad
print(Template(r'''
    void myfunction(\
    %for arg_name, arg_type in arguments:
        ${', ' if loop.index else ''}${arg_type} ${arg_name}\
    %endfor
    )
''').render(arguments=[('string', 'a'), ('int', 'b')]))

# 2) Good but ugly
print(Template(r'''
    void myfunction(\
    %for arg_name, arg_type in arguments:
<%    %>${', ' if loop.index else ''}${arg_type} ${arg_name}\
    %endfor
<%%>)
''').render(arguments=[('string', 'a'), ('int', 'b')]))
```

will print these results:

```
void myfunction(        a string        , b int    )
void myfunction(a string, b int)
```

I want the latter output — so is there a nicer syntax while still keeping my Mako template nicely indented? My solution with an empty `<%   %>` isn't exactly beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of subjective words in this question like *beautiful* and *nice*, and *nicer*.  But I'll give it a try.  Let me know if any of these fit the bill for you.

Note that both of the following do what you ask, but option #1 may be the easiest to read, but it also removes all the white space before the `void`, which may not be intended.  Option #2 should work well for what you describe.

With option #2 below you can substitute whatever character you like best to denote all of the following white space should be deleted.

```py
import re

# 1) Better?
print(Template(r'''
    void myfunction(\
    %for arg_name, arg_type in arguments:
        ${', ' if loop.index else ''}${arg_type} ${arg_name}\
    %endfor
    )
'''.replace('  ', '')).render(arguments=[('string', 'a'), ('int', 'b')]))

# 2) More Better?
print(Template(re.sub(r'>\s*', '', r'''
    void myfunction(\
    %for arg_name, arg_type in arguments:
>       ${', ' if loop.index else ''}${arg_type} ${arg_name}\
    %endfor
>   )
''')).render(arguments=[('string', 'a'), ('int', 'b')]))
```